# Make userscript run on site without DNS

Tags: javascript, dns, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am making a TamperMonkey userscript that is supposed to run on `http://settings.mysite.edu/` (Which has no DNS). Although the script does not run.

Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Settings
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        http://settings.mysite.edu
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>title</title></head><body><h1>body</h1></body>");
})();
```

And of course `mysite.edu` gets replaced with the domain that is real :D

Comment: Insufficient information, but for starters use: `@match *://settings.mysite.edu/*`.  Although if it truly has no DNS, then you may need to replace the domain part with it's IP address.

Comment: @BrockAdams It did not work. What info do you need?